# do not include required files into vim omnicompletion

Tags: ruby, vim, editor, autocomplete

If I try to autocomplete smth in a Ruby file, that has require 'xxx' statement, it starts to scan all files required (and files required by required files as well). and it does that every freakin time!

Is it possible to make vim autocomplete to NOT scan required files or just files in particular path (e.g. app/ only)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the following should work

- `:set path=.,/myinclude1,/myinclude2` to set your own include path
- `:set complete-=i` to disable use of included files in default completion
- `:set include=` to unset the include file matching pattern

I would suggest you use the second one, so `CTRL-X CTRL-I` will still work correctly